# Dynamic form handling

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm creating a dynamic form with core JavaScript.
I am only able to create input fields but I'm not able to handle the values of inputs and also not to apply any functionality...
[image: Dynamic Form]

```js
var formfield = document.getElementById("dynamicForm");

function add() {
  var Price = document.createElement("input");
  Price.setAttribute("type", "text");
  Price.setAttribute("name", "text");
  Price.setAttribute("class", "text");
  Price.setAttribute("placeholder", "Price");
  Price.setAttribute("oninput", "AddValue()");
  Price.setAttribute("style", "margin:2rem ");

  formfield.appendChild(Price);

  var Quantity = document.createElement("input");
  Quantity.setAttribute("type", "text");
  Quantity.setAttribute("name", "text");
  Quantity.setAttribute("class", "text");
  Quantity.setAttribute("placeholder", "Quantity");
  Quantity.setAttribute("style", "margin:2rem ");

  formfield.appendChild(Quantity);

  var Tax = document.createElement("input");
  Tax.setAttribute("type", "text");
  Tax.setAttribute("name", "text");
  Tax.setAttribute("class", "text");
  Tax.setAttribute("placeholder", "Tax");
  Tax.setAttribute("style", "margin:2rem ");

  formfield.appendChild(Tax);
}

function AddValue() {
  console.log("not getting input value");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Tax</td>
          <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <form id="dynamicForm" method="POST"></form>

      <div class="controls">
        <button class="add" onclick="add()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Item
          </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="./form.js"></script>

</html>
```

I want to handle all the values in the input fields.
Don't want to use JQuery or another framework or library

Comment: @Teemu can you please explain how it works?

Comment: No, because I've not a clue of what you need to know. You've to be much more specific.

Comment: This question is too broad. Try to split it down to individual, specific, problems and ask one question for each. The links provided by Teemu give you a place to start. Also, whenever applicable, try to include the relevant code in your question. Thanks.

Comment: @mikabytes Yes you are right but if split this code then it can not be like dynamic  that's why i highlight only three fields

Comment: Show code even if it's no where near complete

Comment: Have you tried to look at the values of the input elements? e.g. document.querySelector('.myinput').value

Comment: @AHaworth it is dynamic. It can not get value by class.

Comment: Not sure why yuu can't use classes since you are creating them yourself - but what exactly do you mean by 'dynamic'? It is important to show us the code you have otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Comment: OK I'm split the show code then show it

Comment: the input should be part of the table. not be outside of the table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dynamic table of input fields, complete with the computation of a total sum for each row:

```js
const tbd = document.querySelector("#dynamicForm table tbody");
document.querySelector("button").onclick=()=>tbd.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="price"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="quantity"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="tax"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="total" disabled></td></tr>`);
tbd.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 [...tbd.children].forEach(tr=>{
  const inps=tr.querySelectorAll("input");
  inps[3].value=((inps[0].value||0)*(inps[1].value||0)*(1+(inps[2].value||0)/100)).toFixed(2)
 })
});
```

```css
input {width:50px}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="dynamicForm" method="POST">
      <table><thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Tax</td>
          <td>Total</td>
        </tr></thead><tbody></tbody>
      </table>
      </form>

      <div class="controls">
        <button class="add" onclick="add()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Item
          </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```